# Calculate fees with Blocktrail/btc.com SDK

Tags: api, php, blocktrail

I want to calculate the fees of a blocktrail transaction with blocktrail SDK, before making the transaction, in order to let the recipient pay fees.

Here is what I tried:

```
$FEES = $wallet->coinSelection(\Blocktrail\SDK\Wallet::normalizeOutputsStruct(['66f4dec6ab29cd056ce1814c6fdfee05e1524b36' =>'100000']),false,false,\Blocktrail\SDK\Wallet::FEE_STRATEGY_LOW_PRIORITY;
echo "$FEES";
$fee = $FEES['fee'];
echo "$fee";
```

But this don't work, it says this: `Fatal error: Uncaught Blocktrail\SDK\Exceptions\BlocktrailSDKException: Address not recognized`

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure as have not used their api system but it could be down to the format of your bitcoin address you are passing in.

`66f4dec6ab29cd056ce1814c6fdfee05e1524b36` is read as a valid bitcoin address using [this service](https://thomas.vanhoutte.be/tools/validate-bitcoin-address.php?address=66f4dec6ab29cd056ce1814c6fdfee05e1524b36&submit=)

However when I [search that address under a block explorer](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/address/1APPGSyMsPaBUAHtjEm6tPqV9U54JRzmd6) I get the following address which starts with the more common 1 `1APPGSyMsPaBUAHtjEm6tPqV9U54JRzmd6`

66f is not a start of a bitcoin address i recognise, though there are many out but [no mention on the wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/List_of_address_prefixes)

Thus I would suggest trying your code with the more common bitcoin address format

```
$FEES = $wallet->coinSelection(\Blocktrail\SDK\Wallet::normalizeOutputsStruct(['1APPGSyMsPaBUAHtjEm6tPqV9U54JRzmd6' =>'100000']),false,false,\Blocktrail\SDK\Wallet::FEE_STRATEGY_LOW_PRIORITY['fee'];
echo "$FEES";
```

And see if that works

Comment: Thanks for reply, but it still don't work, same error

Comment: hmm One thing I would want to verify next would be that the `coinSelection` part of your code is definitely choosing bitcoin?

Comment: Yes, it is bitcoin, the only thing is that I'm using the bitcoin testnet, that I have initialized before, $client = new BlocktrailSDK("api", "api", "BTC", true);

Comment: 66f4dec6ab29cd056ce1814c6fdfee05e1524b36  is a bitcoin test net address

Comment: might be you need to specify the testnet on the fee transaction as well... what are the `false,false` parts submitted after the address? though i would have expected that to have worked with the bitcoin address starting with the 1. So not sure, have you tried speaking directly to their support?

Answer (score 1):

`66f4dec6ab29cd056ce1814c6fdfee05e1524b36` is not a valid Bitcoin address.

Valid Bitcoin addresses on mainnet start with a `1` (P2PKH), `3` (P2SH), or `bc1` (segwit).

On testnet, the addresses start with `m` or `n` (P2PKH), `2` (P2SH), or `tb1` (segwit).

Answer (score 0):

after init wallet

```
$wallet = $client->initWallet("WALLET", "PASS");
```

You can force a fee. I don't know if that will serve you.

```
$fee = 0.0001;

$wallet->pay(array("address" => BlocktrailSDK::toSatoshi(0.00200000)), null, false, false, Wallet::FEE_STRATEGY_FORCE_FEE, BlocktrailSDK::toSatoshi($fee));
```